# send message to log file after package installed

Tags: ubuntu, apt, logs

How can i send a message to a log file (not the apt log) after the installation of a package. I simple want to log which package (package name) was installed. ie. "links installed successfully"

Comment: does `/var/log/dpkg.log` not have the info you need?

Comment: How is the log kept for dpkg.log? Thats what i have a hard time understanding

Comment: too long for a comment, i'll have to make it an answer.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about /var/log/dkpg.log?   The format of the file or what?

Comment: BTW, `apt-get` doesn't actually install/remove the packages itself.  It calls `dpkg` to do that.  so dpkg is able to log every install, upgrade, remove, etc.  The same is true for `aptitude`, `synaptic`, and other front-ends.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 not the format but how exactly the messages within the `dpkg.log` are logged. (Hopefully with that understanding, i could modify it to also log a custom message to a desired log file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/var/log/dpkg.log` should contain the information you want:

From `man dpkg`:

> --log=filename
>
> Log  status  change  updates and actions to filename, instead of the default /var/log/dpkg.log.
>
> If this option is given  multiple times, the  last filename is used.
>
> Log messages are of the form:
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS startup type command` for each dpkg invocation  where  type  is  archives  (with  a  command  of unpack or install)  or  packages  (with  a  command  of  configure,  triggers-only,  remove  or purge);
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS status state pkg installed-version` for status  change  updates;
>
> `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS  action pkg installed-version available-version` for actions where action is  one  of  install,  upgrade,  configure, trigproc,  disappear,  remove or purge;
>
> and `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS conffile filename decision` for conffile changes where  decision is either install or keep.

e.g. I installed `ksh` this morning to investigate a difference between `mksh` and `ksh93`.

```
# grep ksh /var/log/dpkg.log
2015-11-18 09:39:52 install ksh:amd64 <none> 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:52 status half-installed ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:52 status half-installed ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:52 status unpacked ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:52 status unpacked ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:57 configure ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2 <none>
2015-11-18 09:39:57 status unpacked ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:57 status unpacked ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:57 status half-configured ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
2015-11-18 09:39:57 status installed ksh:amd64 93u+20120801-2
```

If you just want to know when packages have been installed or upgraded, try something like this:

```
# zgrep -E '(install|upgrade) bash[: ]' /var/log/dpkg.log*
/var/log/dpkg.log.12.gz:2014-11-25 12:19:59 upgrade bash:amd64 4.3-11 4.3-11+b1
/var/log/dpkg.log.2.gz:2015-09-12 18:52:44 upgrade bash:amd64 4.3-13 4.3-14
/var/log/dpkg.log.4.gz:2015-07-29 10:27:33 upgrade bash:amd64 4.3-12 4.3-13
/var/log/dpkg.log.9.gz:2015-02-09 11:54:56 upgrade bash:amd64 4.3-11+b1 4.3-12
```

The trailing `[: ]` in the regex is to exclude other packages such as `bash-builtins`, `bash-completion`, `bash-doc` etc from the listing.

Answer (score 2):

`logger` can be used for this, like

```
logger package installed successfully
```

Comment: It’s worth noting that this sends a syslog message to a location that’s not necessarily under your control or ability to view, if it is logged at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sudo apt-get install somepackage && echo somepackage installed successfully >> mylogfile.log
```

It's a bit silly, but it answers the exact question you asked.  It only puts the message into mylogfile.log if the install succeeded.

(If that doesn't help, add more detail to your question and I will try to help.)